# $eventTarget.is($(this)) not working

Tags: jquery, targeting

I made a sample accordion. If a tab is being clicked, its siblings are supposed to be closing; in other words, only one tab must be opened if the event target is that current tab (the tabs are the `<header>`s). What I did in my code is test if the event target is the current tab, which is `$(this)`, but it didn't work, nothing changed. How can I fix this?

```js
var $header = $('#accordions').find('header');

$header.on('click', function(e) {
  var $eventTarget = $(e.target);

  if (!$eventTarget.is($(this))) {
    $(this).siblings('.slide').slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.slide').slideToggle(300);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="accordions">
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 1</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 2</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 3</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 4</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your code and make it more succinct by simply retrieving the `.slide` element that is related to the clicked `header` and calling `slideToggle()` on it, then calling `slideUp()` on all the remaining `.slide` elements. Try this:

```js
$('#accordions header').on('click', function(e) {
  var $target = $(this).next('.slide').slideToggle(300);
  $('.slide').not($target).slideUp(300);
});
```

```css
header { font-weight: bold; }
.slide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="accordions">
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 1</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 2</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 3</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <header>Slide 4</header>
    <div class="slide">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```